# Visual Studio Code Intellisense does not work under Linux

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I used the following instructions but I can't seem to make work intellisense with visual studio code under linux: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/ASPnet5

Omnisharp seems to be running with no errors (see screenshot). However, code indentation, find all references, go to definition simply don't work.

[image]

Has anyone managed to make this work under Ubuntu Linux?

Thanks